# Why does webpacker:compile insert a specific hostname in the javascript_pack_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I've just taken over a Webpack project and am new to Webpack.

Project was deploying to Heroku fine. I ran

```
rake webpacker:compile
```

and now, after deploying, I see that

```
javscript_pack_tag 'application'
```

has inserted this in the HTML:

```
<script src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/packs/application.js"></script>
```

How has a hostname and port from localhost made its way into the system? I can see this information in public/packs/manifest.json but how do I configure webpacker to use the relative path so that the pack will be included on any server?

The tag that's been inserted also doesn't include the expiration hash at the end, so it's not found on Heroku even if I do use the right hostname.

I suspect this is because I'm running webpack:compile with development settings. How do I access these settings?

And finally - is it best practice to run webpack:compile as part of the Heroku deployment process, and how do I set this up?

Thanks, 
Louise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but for anyone else who finds themselves here, I just bumped into something similar after upgrading to webpacker/webpack 4.

After some exploring, I noticed that running webpack directly via node did not prepend the hostname. I had a hunch which turned out to be correct: webpacker was using my `ASSET_HOST` environment variable to prefix all my packs, and because I was configuring my development env with a `.env` my development asset host was being used.

Once I moved that to `.env.development` (so it wasn't being referenced as a base env file for production targeted builds as well) all my manifest resources ended being generated with relative paths as expected.

This wasn't a problem with webpacker 3.x, but I guess something in the webpacker 4.x build pipeline must tie in a little more closely with the rails asset pipeline...

Comment: Thanks for leaving this comment, this was the problem with my setup as well.